# Multithreading makes me get the "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" error. Why?

Tags: python, multithreading, file, io, python-multithreading

I am writing a Flask Web Application using WTForms. In one of the forms the user should upload a csv file and the server will analyze the received data. This is the code I am using.

```
filename = token_hex(8) + '.csv'  # Generate a new filename
form.dataset.data.save('myapp/datasets/' + filename)  # Save the received file
dataset = genfromtxt('myapp/datasets/' + filename, delimiter=',')  # Open the newly generated file
# analyze 'dataset'
```

As long as I was using this code inside a single-thread application everything was working. I tried adding a thread in the code. Here's the procedure called by the thread (the same exact code inside a function):

```
def execute_analysis(form):
    filename = token_hex(8) + '.csv'  # Generate a new filename
    form.dataset.data.save('myapp/datasets/' + filename)  # Save the received file
    dataset = genfromtxt('myapp/datasets/' + filename, delimiter=',')  # Open the newly generated file
    # analyze 'dataset'
```

and here's how I call the thread

```
import threading

@posts.route("/estimation", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def estimate_parameters():
    form = EstimateForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        threading.Thread(target=execute_analysis, args=[form]).start()
        flash("Your request has been received. Please check the site in again in a few minutes.", category='success')
        # return render_template('posts/post.html', title=post.id, post=post)
    return render_template('estimations/estimator.html', title='New Analysis', form=form, legend='New Analysis')
```

But now I get the following error:

> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Relative to the `save` function call. Why is it not working? How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without further context, but I suspect it's likely that you're returning from a function or exiting a context manager which causes some file descriptor to close, and hence causes the `save(..)` call to fail with `ValueError`.

If so, one direct fix would be to wait for the thread to finish before returning/closing the file. Something along the lines of:

```
def handle_request(form):
  ...
  analyzer_thread = threading.Thread(target=execute_analysis, args=[form])
  analyzer_thread.start() 
  ...
  analyzer_thread.join() # wait for completion of execute_analysis
  cleanup_context(form)
  return
```

Here is a reproducable minimal example of the problem I am describing:

```
import threading

SEM = threading.Semaphore(0)

def run(fd):
    SEM.acquire() # wait till release
    fd.write("This will fail :(")

fd = open("test.txt", "w+")
other_thread = threading.Thread(target=run, args=[fd])
other_thread.start()

fd.close()
SEM.release() # release the semaphore, so other_thread will acquire & proceed
other_thread.join()
```

Note that the main thread will close the file, and the other thread will fail on `write` call with `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`, as in your case.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I added some code to my original post. So maybe you think the problem is the "parent process" hits the `return` before the thread can perform its tasks? I am surprised this is a problem as the file we are talking about is generated an used only by the given thread. Does the code I added maybe help you understand the issue? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes I think this is exactly what's happening. Note that the __uploaded file__ is likely being closed -- not the file you're writing to at `'myapp/datasets/' + filename`. You can check this by trying adding a `analyzer_thread.join()` right before the return, which'd make it wait for returning before the analysis is done. If this is the case, you probably should read this temprorary incoming file into memory (if possible), so you wouldn't have to worry about open/close file descriptors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer again: to solve the issue I decided to let the main thread perform the initial operation on the file (i.e. `save`) while the rest is being performed by the new thread (the main calculation and also the reason why I want a multi-threaded application). Now I get a different kind of error, maybe you know how to fix it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64293912/why-child-threads-cannot-access-the-current-user-variable-in-flask-login

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the framework sufficiently to tell exactly what happened, but I can tell you how you probably can fix it.

Whenever you have a resource that is shared by multiple threads, use a lock.

```py
from threading import Lock

LOCK = Lock()

def process():

    LOCK.acquire()
    ...  # open a file, write some data to it etc.
    LOCK.release()

    # alternatively, use the context manager syntax
    with LOCK:
        ...

threading.Thread(target=process).start()
threading.Thread(target=process).start()
```

[Documentation on `threading.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html):

> The class implementing primitive lock objects. Once a thread has acquired a lock, subsequent attempts to acquire it block, until it is released

Basically, after thread 1 calls `LOCK.acquire()`, subsequent calls e.g. from other threads, will cause those threads to freeze and wait until something calls `LOCK.release()` (usually thread 1, after it finishes its business with the resource).

If the filenames are randomly generated then I wouldn't expect problems with 1 thread closing the other's file, unless both of them happen to generate the same name. But perhaps you can figure it out with some experimentation, e.g. first try locking calls to both `save` and `genfromtxt` and check if that helps. It might also make sense to add some `print` statements (or even better, use `logging`), e.g. to check if the file names don't collide.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! The file that generates the issue is created and used only by the thread... How can this generate a conflict with the original process? Btw I added some code to the original post, I hope it can help solve the issue :) thanks again!

Comment: Btw I tried wrapping the file operations with the LOCK statements as you suggested but it behaves the same. I think the problem may be that the original process hits return before the thread can perform its task