# Why child threads cannot access the current_user variable in flask_login?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, python-multithreading, flask-login

I am writing a **Flask application** and I am trying to insert a **multi-threaded implementation** for certain server related features. I noticed this weird behavior so I wanted to understand why is it happening and how to solve it. I have the following code:

```
from flask_login import current_user, login_required
import threading

posts = Blueprint('posts', __name__)

@posts.route("/foo")
@login_required
def foo():
    print(current_user)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=goo)
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
    return


def goo():
    print(current_user)
    # ...
```

The main process correctly prints the `current_user`, while the child thread prints `None`.

```
User('Username1', 'email1@email.com', 'Username1-ProfilePic.jpg')
None
```

Why is it happening? How can I manage to obtain the `current_user` also in the child process? I tried passing it as argument of `goo` but I still get the same behavior.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47952830/flask-login-current-user) but I can't understand how to ensure the context is not changing in this situation, so I tried providing a simpler example.

### A partially working workaround

I tried passing as parameter also a newly created object `User` populated with the data from `current_user`

```
def foo():
    # ...
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=current_user.username).first_or_404()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=goo, args=[user])
    # ...

def goo(user):
    print(user)
    # ...
```

And it correctly prints the information of the current user. But since inside `goo` I am also performing database operations I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function
> or push an application context. See
> http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.

So as I suspected I assume it's a problem of context.

I tried also inserting this inside `goo` as suggested by the error:

```
def goo():
    from myapp import create_app
    app = create_app()
    app.app_context().push()
    # ... database access
```

But I still get the same errors and if I try to print `current_user` I get `None`.

How can I pass the old context to the new thread? Or should I create a new one?

Comment: Have you tried the recommendations in that link? The one with using `with app.app_context():` for instance.

Comment: I'm new to the framework so I don't know if I'm doing correctly, but I tried nesting everything inside of `goo` inside a `with create_app().app_context():` statement and the behaviour is still the same. (I used `create_app()` as using Blueprints I don't have a direct reference to `app`, but I have a feeling what I did was totally wrong)

Comment: @Cihan I added the answer to your question in the original post. Thanks again for the support!

Comment: Hmm I was thinking you had an app already as described in that document. In that case I don't know enough about Flask/Sqlalchemy to comment further. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Flask uses thread local variables to store this for each request's thread. That simplifies in many cases, but makes it hard to use multiple threads. See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/design/#thread-local.

If you want to use multiple threads to handle a single request, Flask might not be the best choice. You can always interact with Flask exclusively on the initial thread if you want and then forward anything you need on other threads back and forth yourself through a shared object of some kind. For database access on secondary threads, you can use a thread-safe database library with multiple threads as long as Flask isn't involved in its usage.

In summary, treat Flask as single threaded. Any extra threads shouldn't interact directly with Flask to avoid problems. You can also consider either not using threads at all and run everything sequentially or trying e.g. Tornado and asyncio for easier concurrency with coroutines depending on the needs.

Answer (score 0):

your server serves multiple users, wich are threads by themself.
flask_login was not designed for extra threading in it, thats why child thread prints None.

i suggest u to use db for transmit variables from users and run addition docker container if you need separate process.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `current_user` is implement as a local safe resource:
https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/main/flask_login/utils.py#L26

Read:
https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/local/#module-werkzeug.local